# Pass data between storyboards using swift

Tags: ios, swift3

An app in one device with 3 storyboards: Main, Rider, Driver.
In Driver storyboard, DriverVC.swift, when driver accepts a ride, variable: "acceptedRyde = true" needs to be passed to Rider storyboard, RiderVC to trigger an alert to pop up in the Rider Storyboard.

How can this be done?

Comment: You should use local notification for that.

Comment: you should explain WHY, rather than simply declaring an opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@LizG - This should be fairly straightforward to implement through something like Firebase.

In many Firebase applications, you will see data stored with the current user ID as the initial key, but if you do that here, then no-one else will be able to access the data.

The simplest implementation you could have a list of rides like this...
[image]

and then you don't need to push anything to the drivers, just have them watching for changes with something like this

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "Rides")
    ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "status").queryEqual(toValue: "requested").observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let rides = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] ?? [:]
        for ride in rides
        {
            print(ride)
            // update the list of available rides
        }
    })
```

When you get into accepting rides, you will have to be careful to make sure that two drivers don't try to do it at the same time - so include a step of try to accept it, then check to see if you managed

The Firebase examples are extensive, and should show you everything you need

Answer (score 1):

You can use `prepare(for:sender:)`. See [documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621490-prepare)

Basically, when you are about to segue to the new view controller, read the current values you have and pass them to the view controller you are going to. This can be used to tell it to trigger an alert.

**EXAMPLE** (off the top of my head)

```
class ViewControllerOne: UIViewController {

    var acceptedRide: Bool = false

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "YOUR_SEGUE_IDENTIFIER" {
            if let destinationViewController = segue.destination as? ViewControllerTwo {
                destinationViewController.showAlert = acceptedRide
            }
        }
    }

}

class ViewControllerTwo: UIViewController {
    var showAlert: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            if showAlert {
                // SHOW ALERT
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** You may not want to use a `didSet` to show an alert. You need to decide the correct time to show the alert.

Comment: I added a quick (untested) example. It should give you at least a starting point.

Comment: This answer was written under the impression you was going to be moving to a new view controller via a segue but after reading comments on the other answer I don't believe this is what you want to do and thus this answer is probably now redundant.

Answer (score 0):

```
let rider = UIStoryboard(name: "Driver", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RirderVC") as! RiderVC
rider.acceptedRyde = true

self.present(rider, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You need to set RiderVC as storyboard identifier on your RiderVC.

I asume that you have a acceptRyde variable in your RiderVC.

```
var acceptRyde: Bool?
```

If you want to show an alert just add a code in your viewDidLoad

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Ride Accepted", message: "your message", preferredStyle: .alert)
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))

self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Where does this code go?  In Driver? In viewDidLoad?  I tried doing it like this and my app jumps from driver to rider which cant happen. This is like an uber app where you're either a driver or a rider

Comment: Oh ok, so use a local notificaiton like @Poles suggestion. If the view cannot jump from driver to rider, why you execute code in riderVC? it must be unreachable

Comment: You must find a way that keeps your app modules separated.

Comment: yes, that is why I put them in separate storyboards.  But like I said, I need to trigger an alert to tell the rider that the driver has accepted the request once the driver accepts the request.  the way to do that is by passing the variable and value of "acceptedRyde = true"

Comment: Driver and Rider are in separated devices then right?

Comment: This is one app - for separate devices.  Either you sign up for Driver or Rider.

Comment: separate devices?  Then you're going to need to send an alert as an external message - any number of ways you could do that, but you could implement it through something like Firebase with a list of rides of status available, accepted, completed...

Comment: Yeah firebase is one of the best solutions, there is a very clear documentation with examples to work with, so check it out. https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup

Comment: What you need is more than pass a boolean value to a controller. First read the docs, and understand them. Then you can be able to implement in your app.

Comment: @Russell how would I do this through Firebase? Push Notifications?